# Vue Jest - Div element still exists when v-if is false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I have a small project where I am learning to write jest Unit tests in Vue. Inside this project I have a HiChild component which gets a message props. When the length of this message is smaller then 3 then a error div should show. I use `v-if="error"` to check if the I should show the div or not.

This is the component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>The child says {{ message }}</h2>
    <div class="error" v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      default: "Hello",
    },
  },
  computed: {
    error() {
      return this.message.trim().length < 3
        ? " The child can say bigger words than that!"
        : "";
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

But in the unit test I wrote for this component I have a test where I test if the div actually
exists when the error variable is not empty and not exist when it is empty. But the test does not pass when it should be empty.
This is the unit test I wrote:

```
describe('HiChild.vue', () => {
  it('renders error when message is too short', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HiChild, {
      propsData: { message: 'hi' },
    });
    expect(wrapper.find('.error').exists()).toBe(true);

    wrapper.setProps({ message: 'good day to you!' });
    expect(wrapper.find('.error').exists()).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

And here is the output from the test:

[image]

Comment: Why do you expect `message: 'good day to you!'` to make it false?

Answer (score 0):

Because :

```
 computed: {
    error() {
      return this.message.trim().length < 3
        ? " The child can say bigger words than that!"
        : "";
    },
```

"" is different to false

```
"" !== false
```

return directly false like that

```
 computed: {
    error() {
      return this.message.trim().length < 3
        ? " The child can say bigger words than that!"
        : false;
    },
```

Regards

Comment: When I change it to false the test still does not pass.

Comment: It's `exists()` that is asserted, and it's boolean.